# PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: - character varying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3.2 I'm trying to order a table in descending order using the minus syntax. eg: Costing.order("-name")

This works for integer columns but not for string fields, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: - character varying
LINE 1: ...costing_id" WHERE "charges"."division_id" = 3 ORDER BY -name
```

I am aware that I can do a "name desc" instead. I have a plugin I'm trying to use in which uses the minus syntax by default so I was wondering if there is a way Rails can do this easily.

**Update**

Just tried this in Rails 4.2.5.1 and it also doesn't work.